# C++ circular dependency with intrusive linked list

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, circular-dependency, intrusive-containers

I've implemented this intrusive linked list:

```
template <class Entry>
struct LinkedListNode {
    Entry *next;
    Entry *prev;
};

template <class Entry, LinkedListNode<Entry> Entry::*NodeMember>
class LinkedList {
public:
    void init ();
    bool isEmpty () const;
    Entry * first () const;
    Entry * last () const;
    Entry * next (Entry *e) const;
    Entry * prev (Entry *e) const;
    void prepend (Entry *e);
    void append (Entry *e);
    void insertBefore (Entry *e, Entry *target);
    void insertAfter (Entry *e, Entry *target);
    void remove (Entry *e);

public:
    Entry *m_first;
    Entry *m_last;
};

...
template <class Entry, LinkedListNode<Entry> Entry::*NodeMember>
inline Entry * LinkedList<Entry, NodeMember>::next (Entry *e) const
{
    return (e->*NodeMember).next;
}
...
```

It can be used like this:

```
struct MyEntry {
    int value;
    LinkedListNode<MyEntry> list_node;
};

LinkedList<MyEntry, &MyEntry::list_node> list;
list.init();
MyEntry entry1, entry2;
entry1.value = 3;
list.append(&entry1);
entry2.value = 5;
list.prepend(&entry2);
```

It works all right, until you need two objects which contain lists of one another:

```
struct MyEntry2;

struct MyEntry1 {
    int value;
    LinkedListNode<MyEntry1> node;
    LinkedList<MyEntry2, &MyEntry2::node> list;
};

struct MyEntry2 {
    int value;
    LinkedListNode<MyEntry2> node;
    LinkedList<MyEntry1, &MyEntry1::node> list;
};
```

Each MyEntry1 holds a list of MyEntry2's, and each MyEntry2 can only appear in the list of one MyEntry1; and the converse. However, this doesn't compile, because the member pointer &MyEntry2::node is taken before MyEntry2 is defined:

```
prog.cpp:33:27: error: incomplete type 'MyEntry2' used in nested name specifier
prog.cpp:33:41: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

There isn't really any practical semantic to this problematic layout, it is only a theoretical problem I've found which may limit the usability of the generic linked list.

Is there any way around this which doesn't make the list considerably more impractical?

**EDIT**: the layout of all data structures here is completely defined. This is because the data members of LinkedList do not depend on the problematic NodeMember template parameter; only the functions do. The problem seems to be that the language is demanding that &MyEntry2::node be known even though it does not really need to be known at the time.

**EDIT**: it must be possible to use this generic list to add a structure into two or more lists; this is the purpose of the NodeMember template parameter - it specifies which LinkedListNode within the entry is to be used.

Comment: I think it actually does need to be known at the time. You are referencing a member that has yet to be declared, just because you haven't made an instance of the structure does not mean that your compiler is not looking for that member when it parses the line. I have only used forward declarations of structures when I am using only its identifier, not one of its members. Perhaps I am wrong, but circular dependencies also confuse me =P

Comment: You can also implement the hooks through inheritance. This would solve the problem and is cleaner imo, its intrusive anyway.

Comment: Also, could you give us an idea why you don't want to use STL lists?

Comment: @CrazyCasta There are many justifications for intrusive lists. I don't think this is necessary here.

Comment: @CrazyCasta this question is not about intrusive versus non-intrusive data structures. My question is about intrusive lists, for whatever reasons I have. I haven't looked at boost intrusive, but I suspect they suffer from the same problem.

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak They shouldn't because you can inherit from the hooks.

Comment: @pmr What's the difference between the code shown and just using std::list<MyEntry2> *list; in MyEntry1 and std::list<MyEntry1> *list; in MyEntry2.

Comment: @CrazyCasta [This](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/intrusive/intrusive_vs_nontrusive.html) should give you some motivating examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an implementation using inheritance that does not suffer from
your problem.

```
template <typename Entry>
struct LinkedListNode {
    Entry *next;
    Entry *prev;
};

template <class Entry>
class LinkedList {
public:
    void init ();
    bool isEmpty () const;
    Entry * first () const;
    Entry * last () const;
    Entry* next (Entry* e) const {
        return e->next;  
    }
    Entry * prev (Entry *e) const;
    void prepend (Entry *e);
    void append (Entry *e);
    void insertBefore (Entry *e, Entry *target);
    void insertAfter (Entry *e, Entry *target);
    void remove (Entry *e);
public:
    LinkedListNode<Entry> *m_first;
    LinkedListNode<Entry> *m_last;
};

struct MyEntry2;

struct MyEntry1 : public LinkedListNode<MyEntry1> {
    int value;
    LinkedList<MyEntry2> list;
};

struct MyEntry2 : public LinkedListNode<MyEntry2> {
    int value;
    LinkedList<MyEntry1> list;
};
```

Here is a solution where the LinkedList has a functor as second
template argument. We use an accessor functor with a templated
`operator()` to remove code duplication and to delay look-up of the
name. **Note:** The accessor should actually be a member and treated with an
empty base optimization.

```
template <class Entry>
struct LinkedListNode {
    Entry *next;
    Entry *prev;
};

template <class Entry, typename Func>
class LinkedList {
public:
    void init ();
    bool isEmpty () const;
    Entry * first () const;
    Entry * last () const;
    Entry * next (Entry *e) const {
      Func f;
      return f(e).next();
    }
    Entry * prev (Entry *e) const;
    void prepend (Entry *e);
    void append (Entry *e);
    void insertBefore (Entry *e, Entry *target);
    void insertAfter (Entry *e, Entry *target);
    void remove (Entry *e);

public:
    Entry *m_first;
    Entry *m_last;
};

struct MyEntry2;

struct node_m_access {
  template <typename T>
  LinkedListNode<T> operator()(T* t) const {
    return t->node;
  }
};

struct MyEntry1 {
    int value;
    LinkedListNode<MyEntry1> node;
    LinkedList<MyEntry2, node_m_access> list;
};

struct MyEntry2 {
    int value;
    LinkedListNode<MyEntry2> node;
    LinkedList<MyEntry1, node_m_access> list;
};
```

Comment: How do I make a structure a member of multiple independent linked lists?

Comment: The whole purpose of the member pointer parameter was to allow that.

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak You might want to add that to your question. It is an important requirement.

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak Now there is a second solution using an accessor_functor with a templated `operator()`.

Comment: This works fine, thanks. I've also made a small modification to make it easier to use (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

This problem is equivalent to trying to do:

```
struct MyEntry2;

struct MyEntry1 {
    MyEntry2 a;
};

struct MyEntry2 {
    MyEntry1 b;
};
```

In the above case, the compiler needs to know the size of the MyEntry2 struct when generating MyEntry1. In your case, the compiler needs to know the offset of node in MyEntry2 while generating MyEntry1.

I'm not experienced in template-foo but I would guess that instead of making Entry a class, you want to use a pointer to a class.

Comment: See my edit. The layout and size of LinkedList can be determined without knowing what the NodeMember template parameter is. After all, a LinkedList is just a pair of pointers (and the sizes of pointers are known after an incomplete declaration). See how the declaration of LinkedList doesn't really use NodeMember.

Comment: But it can't know what `::node` is, because you didn't define `MyEntry2`.

Comment: I was editing this while you made your comment, please let me know if you're still confused. It's the access to the NodeMember* not the size of the LinkedList that matters.

Comment: @DeadMG I get why it doesn't work. I'm asking how to make it work.

Comment: Well, you can't, because what you're doing is a fundamental circular dependency.

Comment: Also, changing the physical layout of anything here is not an option. It has to be like that for performance and ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small modification of pmr's accessor solution to reduce the amount of boilerplate. The trick is to first provide an incomplete "struct" declaration of the accessors, instantiate the LinkedList's with these, and later complete the accessors by inheriting from a template accessor class.

```
template <class Entry>
struct LinkedListNode {
    Entry *next;
    Entry *prev;
};

template <class Entry, class Accessor>
class LinkedList {
public:
    void init ();
    bool isEmpty () const;
    Entry * first () const;
    Entry * last () const;
    Entry * next (Entry *e) const {
        return Accessor::access(e).next;
    }
    Entry * prev (Entry *e) const;
    void prepend (Entry *e);
    void append (Entry *e);
    void insertBefore (Entry *e, Entry *target);
    void insertAfter (Entry *e, Entry *target);
    void remove (Entry *e);

public:
    Entry *m_first;
    Entry *m_last;
};

template <class Entry, LinkedListNode<Entry> Entry::*NodeMember>
struct LinkedListAccessor {
    static LinkedListNode<Entry> & access (Entry *e)
    {
        return e->*NodeMember;
    }
};

struct MyEntry2;
struct Accessor1;
struct Accessor2;

struct MyEntry1 {
    int value;
    LinkedListNode<MyEntry1> node;
    LinkedList<MyEntry2, Accessor2> list;
};

struct MyEntry2 {
    int value;
    LinkedListNode<MyEntry2> node;
    LinkedList<MyEntry1, Accessor1> list;
};

struct Accessor1 : LinkedListAccessor<MyEntry1, &MyEntry1::node> {};
struct Accessor2 : LinkedListAccessor<MyEntry2, &MyEntry2::node> {};
```

With this, a convenience class can even be made for when there is no problem with the circular dependency:

```
template <class Entry, LinkedListNode<Entry> Entry::*NodeMember>
class SimpleLinkedList
: public LinkedList<Entry, LinkedListAccessor<Entry, NodeMember> >
{};
```